# PHP function within echo and html

Tags: php, html, function

I am trying to color a row based on a function.
I run it to return a color (red, green, ...) that will assign a class.

But what is wrong?

```
echo "<td class=\"" .  <?php Color($row['Col3']); ?> . "\">" . $row['Col3'] . "</td>";
```

It is throwing the following error:

> PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected '<' in D:\App\index.php on line 67

This is the function:

```
function Color($value) {    
    if ($value > 100) return 'red';
    if ($value < 100) return 'green';
}
```

I checked it 50 times and can't find where is this unexpected "<". Everything is in place for me.

Comment: Don't put a `<?php` tag inside of an echo. `echo "<td class=\"" .  Color($row['Col3']) . "\">" . $row['Col3'] . "</td>";`

Comment: Oh god, seems easy now... Thanks!